# Django Makemigrations and Migrate are slow

Tags: python, django, migration

Ever since the project updated to Django 1.8 (1.8.7 to be precise) from Django 1.7.6, makemigrations and migrate are super slow (it takes about 15 minutes to migrate around 10 migrations).

When I make 'manage.py migrate' 90% of the time is making 'Rendering model states...', before giving me 'DONE'.

Anyone knows why this is happening?

Comment: You might need to see what's happening when you are doing migration. I only used mysql so just in case you use the same database you can login into dbshell and do `show processlist;` to see the connections.

Comment: I'm use PostgreSQL. I will try to do that to see what's is going on.

Comment: That seems impossibly slow for 10 migrations. It might be worth it to upgrade to 1.9, rendering performance is a _lot_ better. Anyway, could you share your migrations? Otherwise it's just guesswork as to why they're so slow.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with Django 1.8 unfortunately the only solution supported by django is to upgrade.